# Onsen UI: Back and Menu Button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

The mobile app is Onsen UI based, I'm trying to manage both Android's Back and Menu Button. So my question is split into 2.

First how to slide the app menu when the use clicks on device's menu button (especially Samsung)?

The second issue is about the Mobile Device Back button (hardware) when clicking on it, it exists the application while it should return to homepage and if on homepage the client should click twice to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Onsen team answered your question on their forums regarding the backbutton, but for others here are some resources:

backbutton with Onsen simply issues popPage.  If there is not a page to pop, it will exit the app.  For more information on controlling that behavior, see this:

https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton

```
ons.setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener(function() {
  if (navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure to close the app?",
    function(index) {
      if (index === 1) { // OK button
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // Close the app
      }
    }
  ));
});
```

For the menu button, you just need to add an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.menubutton.html